# TokenAccountNotFoundError

Tags: spl-token, token, spl-token-program

I am a new developer trying to learn and dive into the Solana ecosystem. I'm currently trying to complete this lab: https://www.soldev.app/course/token-program.

I'm on step 2 of the lab, where you create a token mint. Based on the logs, the Token Mint is completing successfully, but it's failing on const mintInfo = await token.getMint(connection, mint);

Here is the function I am trying to run:

```
async function main() {
    const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"))
    const user = await initializeKeypair(connection)

    const mint = await createNewMint(
        connection,
        user,
        user.publicKey,
        user.publicKey,
        2
    )

    const mintInfo = await token.getMint(connection, mint);
}
```

Here is the error output I'm getting:

```
(base) ➜  token git:(main) ✗ npm run start

> solana-course-client@1.0.0 start
> ts-node src/index.ts

bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
PublicKey: 3qPfaEpTANysCPvSEUdDFmPk9wH5nCoR9L75Q7oiWpVt
Token Mint: https://explorer.solana.com/address/6jsanoaZKCmrKkaGqbtuZNrpnwqpX9GGJgqhjyYNpmvj?cluster=devnet
TokenAccountNotFoundError
    at unpackMint (/Users/kapforty/Documents/Projects/Solana Development Course/token/node_modules/@solana/spl-token/src/state/mint.ts:95:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kapforty/Documents/Projects/Solana Development Course/token/node_modules/@solana/spl-token/src/state/mint.ts:82:12)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/kapforty/Documents/Projects/Solana Development Course/token/node_modules/@solana/spl-token/lib/cjs/state/mint.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a "confirmed" commitment on the connection. It may just be that `getMint` is trying to fetch the account data before the transaction to create the account has been confirmed.

```
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
```